# JS modules: import function from superior module and call it on change

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to invoke a function in js modules from a superior module which doesn't know, which or how many modules are affected by the function?

**A short example:**

This could be a structure. **Please note** that `app.js` doesnt't know, how many or which instances of the class `Module` are used.

`app.js`

```
const somethingChanged = () => {
    console.log('>> Button was clicked and something changed. ')
}

(function () {
    const button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        somethingChanged();
    });
})();

export {
    somethingChanged
}
```

`module.js`

```
import { somethingChanged } from './app.js'

export default class Module {
    constructor() {
    }

    calledWhenSomethingChanged() {
        // This function should be called when the function somethingChanged was invoked by app.js
    }
}
```

So, `app.js` has a button which triggers the function `somethingChanged` when the button was clicked. There is a unknowm amount of instances of the class `Module` in another part of the js, so
`app.js` do not know them.

The modules `module.js` import the function `somethingChanged` from `app.js`. When this function is invoked by `app.js`, the class `Module` should call the function `calledWhenSomethingChanged`.

Maybe this is something like a "reverse callback". Just want to know if something like this is possible. The other alternative would be to include the `button.addEventListener` to the class `Module`.

Comment: why not keep every instances of `class Module` in a list in `app.js` and do a `list.forEach( item => item.calledWhenSomethingChanged() )` when button is clicked ?
Why `app.js` doesnt't know, how many or which instances of the class Module are used ?

Comment: This is because the whole structure of the project. I can access `class Module` and `app.js` but not the "global handling" of the modules, so my `app.js` has no information about how many or which instances of `class Module` exist. But my (for me interesting) questing is: it a structure as showed above is possible? Or is there no way to realize this in js?

Comment: and about passing the button click handler in the class constructor ? Where the Module(s) are instantiate ?

Comment: I do not have access to the initialization of the instance so it is not possible.

Comment: can you explicit the current structure a little more ? ( and how the files are bound )

Comment: This is quiet complex. Lets say that we've a API (we get from a other dev group). This API handles all the initialization and administration of the `class Module`. I have access to the `class Module` to implement user-defined stuff, for instance the appearance of the `class Module` in the DOM. Using the API I can initialize the whole application and so on but I have no access to all `class Module` instances. What I want to do now is to transfer a callback funtion (click event)  to these `class Module` instances because after changing the color theme, the appearance changes, too.

Comment: and can you register all `calledWhenSomethingChanged()` methods in an array in the `window` object and call them all in `app.js` in the event handler ?
if you really want me to try to help you, you can create reproduce a minimalist version of this on https://codesandbox.io/ for example